# The right way to compare two variable php

Tags: php

Im trying to compare 2 variables which contain these query results

Query :

```
$cekFitur = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM selected_feature"));

$totalTerm = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM token_preprocessing_latih"));

if (($cekFitur && $totalTerm) == 0) {
    do something
}else{
    do something
}
```

Is this the correct way to check those 2 variables together ?

Please tell me if I have to change something in my code.
Thank you.

Comment: way not `if ($cekFitur == 0 && $totalTerm == 0) {`??

Comment: you are comparing wrong, you should be doing, `if ($cekFitur == 0 && $totalTerm == 0)`

Comment: `if(($var == 0) && ($var2 ==0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `($cekFitur && $totalTerm) == 0` is comparing like

`($var1 == true && $var2 == true) == 0` = `true OR false == 0` = `1 OR 0 == 0`

This is not what you want. You've to compare them individually.

```
if ($cekFitur == 0 && $totalTerm == 0) {
```